# wordpress как ограничить вывод символов <?php the_content(); ?>

Tags: wordpress

при выводе поста с блогом нужно чтобы ещё кроме картинки и названия статьи выводилось ещё краткое описание самой статьи, но это описание очень большое как можно ограничить количество символов до 30-40 и чтобы в конце было троеточие?

```
<?php
/* Template Name: blog */
get_header(); ?>
<article>
    <section class="mblog">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="mblog__wrapper">
                <?php $query = new WP_Query( 'cat=6' ); ?>
                <?php if ( $query->have_posts() ) : while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post(); ?>
                    <div class="mblog__col">
                        <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" class="mblog__post-item">
                            <div class="mblog__post-img-wp js-bg-img">
                                <?php the_post_thumbnail();?>
                            </div>
                            <div class="mblog__post-title"><?php the_title(); ?></div>
                            <div class="mblog__post-content"><?php the_content(); ?></div>
                            </div>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                <?php endwhile;
                    wp_reset_postdata();
                else : ?>
                    <p><?php esc_html_e( 'Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.' ); ?></p>
                <?php endif; ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
</article>
<?php
get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: https://wp-kama.ru/id_31/obrezka-teksta-zamenyaem-the-excerpt.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> function.php

```
<?php   
    add_filter("the_content", "plugin_myContentFilter");

    function plugin_myContentFilter($content)
    { 
     return mb_substr($content, 0, 30);
    }
?>
```

А так же:
[wp_trim_words](https://wp-kama.ru/function/wp_trim_words)

Comment: Вот `wp_trim_words()` - это хорошо, а `substr()` - это прямо **совсем плох�** - обрезка может происходить в середине слова или даже разрезать unicode-последовательность

Comment: @tutankhamun вот да. Предлагать на русском StackOverflow функцию substr() просто неприлично.

Comment: @KAGGDesign улица воспитала.

Comment: @KAGGDesign обновил, так лучше?)

Comment: @Даниил вот так совсем другое дело))